# Permission denied on jquery.min.js file in DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, permissions, permission-denied

I have created some jQuery and put it in an ascx include. It works fine on regular pages, however when I load a secured page on my site I get the following javascript error.

---

Permission Denied
jquery.min.js
Code: 0

---

Any ideas?

Comment: I've managed to get some more information out of the debugger. It says:


Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount" code: "1

{if(ctl.parentNode.childNodes[i+offset]!=null)  dnn.js (line 176)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the hosted jQuery by the Google CDN, you can change the hosted script address to use https instead of http:

Host -> Host Settings -> Advanced Settings -> jQuery Settings ->

[image: Screenshot of Host Settings]

**References**

- [DotNetNuke Gemini Bug Report](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

**Updated**

This permissions error can occur when you're attempting to make an $.ajax() request using jQuery from a secure URL (https) to a non-secure URL (http) even though they are the same domain. Changing the `url` parameter to use a relative URL should fix the issue.

Comment: Lance, I changed to the below but I am still getting the same message. The file is definitely there because I copied and pasted the location from the URL below:
https://www.mywebsite.com/resources/shared/scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the jQuery min file?  If you are using a fully qualified URL to the library, and that URL specifies HTTP rather than HTTPS, this would cause the error you describe.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This would cause errors if your site was being served under HTTPS.

Comment: I'm not actually making any explicit reference to it. DNN has jquery built into it by default. It appears to work ok without a reference, but just not in SSL

Comment: I'm going to take a shot and guess that DNN is probably referencing jQuery through a CDN like Google:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js 

Note the HTTP in the URL, that would cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the "Permission Denied" error comes from trying to access a window that is in a different domain than you.  In the code that you listed, is `ctl` a reference to a popup window, or some window other than the window that the code is running in?  If that window is at http://mysite.com and your script is running on https://mysite.com, you'll get the Permission Denied error.